# Combining a TRANSFORM......PIVOT and a UNION Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

it's my first time posting here but this site has supplied me with lots of answers in the past so I'll give it a try.

Background information: I'm using Acces 2013, connecting to a MySQL database through ODBC 3.51.

I'm busy pulling reports out of a Call Detail record, namely I want to make an overview of the times different employees have spent receiving and making outgoing calls on different phone lines.

I have already found out I can't make two seperate TRANSFORM...PIVOT query's and UNION those. That makes sense, because there's no way the code knows my 2 query's will return the same amount of Pivots.

Is it possible to turn this process around? (First collect the data you need in a UNION, and then transforming the data).

I created the following Union query collecting the relevant data:

```
(SELECT dbo_IpPbxCDR.DestinationName AS [Name], Sum(DateDiff('n',[dbo_IpPbxCDR.starttime],[dbo_IpPbxCDR.endtime])) AS [Called Time], IIf((dbo_IpPbxCDR.CalledName Like "*0900*") OR (dbo_IpPbxCDR_1.CalledName like "*0900*"), "0900", "abo") AS [Called Line]
FROM (dbo_IpPbxCDR AS dbo_IpPbxCDR_1 RIGHT JOIN dbo_IpPbxCDR ON dbo_IpPbxCDR_1.CallId = dbo_IpPbxCDR.TransferredCallId2)
WHERE <Where clause relevant to the data I want. It’s pretty long so I omitted it>
GROUP BY dbo_IpPbxCDR.DestinationName, IIf((dbo_IpPbxCDR.CalledName Like "*0900*") OR (dbo_IpPbxCDR_1.CalledName like "*0900*"), "0900", "abo"))
UNION
(SELECT dbo_IpPbxCDR.OriginationName AS [Name], Sum(DateDiff('n',[dbo_IpPbxCDR.starttime],[dbo_IpPbxCDR.endtime])) AS [Called Time], 'uit' AS [Called Line]
FROM dbo_IpPbxCDR
WHERE <Where clause relevant to the data I want. It’s pretty long so I omitted it>
GROUP BY dbo_IpPbxCDR.OriginationName)
```

I'm trying to transform on `Sum(DateDiff('n',[dbo_IpPbxCDR.starttime],[dbo_IpPbxCDR.endtime]))` so I can get data relevant to certain months with `pivot Month([dbo_IpPbxCDR.starttime])`

I'd appreciate any help/advice I can get!

Comment: Is this really MySQL?

Comment: I'm connecting to a MySQL database but I'm using Access for my Query-ing. In the past I've understood Access's Jet Engine takes over certain tasks, but I'm still far from understanding which part of my Query is handled by MySQL and which part by the Jet Engine

Comment: What happens if you save the UNION query in Access and then use that saved query as the basis for your crosstab query?

Comment: I managed to make it work with
TRANSFORM XXX
SELECT XXX
FROM (
union query here
)
GROUP BY XXX
PIVOT XXX

This probably amounts to the same thing as you suggested. Thanks for the advice anyway! I'll try it out and see if it may improve on performance.

Comment: You might consider using Pass Through Queries so that all of the processing and query language would be MySQL.